# Error con sqlite3 y Python al añadir datos

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

Tengo la siguiente base de datos creada:

```
miConexion=sqlite3.connect("factura.db")
        
        miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
        try:
            miCursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE NUEVAFACTURA (
                ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                CODIGO VARCHAR(50),
                UNIDADES INTEGER,
                CONCEPTO VARCHAR(25),
                PRECIO REAL,
                SUB REAL)
                ''')
            messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "BBDD Creada con exito")    
        except:
            messagebox.showwarning("Atencion!","La BBDD ya existe")
```

Al intentar añadir los datos, con el siguiente código, me da el error: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type.

```
var_subtotal1=float(var_unidades.get() * var_precio.get())
            var_observaciones="prueba"
            miConexion=sqlite3.connect("factura.db")
            miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
            """miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO NUEVAFACTURA VALUES(NULL, '" +var_codigo.get()+
            "','"+var_unidades.get()+
            "','"+var_cancepto.get()+
            "','"+ var_precio.get()+
            "','"+ var_subtotal1.get()+"')")"""
            datos = var_codigo.get(),var_unidades.get(),var_concepto.get(),var_precio,var_subtotal1
            miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO NUEVAFACTURA VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?)",(datos))
            miConexion.commit()
            messagebox.showinfo("BBDD","Registro guardado")
```

Necesito que los datos se añadan a la base de datos. Añadiendo tambien el resultado de precio * unidad a la columna subtotal1.

Comment: ¿Has probado si te devuelve el valor de las variables con el mismo tipo de datos?

Comment: Sabiendo que estás trabajando con tkinter y que `var_precio` y `var_subtotal1` son entrys o variables de control, te olvidaste de ponerles el `.get()` al final. Tal y como está tu código, sqlite trata de adaptar el objeto de Tkinter en algo compatible con sqlite y no lo logra. De ahí el error.

Comment: Voto por cerrar la pregunta por que la causa del problema es un error tipografico